# cryptsetup/luks backend can use openssl evp interface?

Tags: luks, openssl, cryptsetup

I'm trying to use cryptsetup with some hardware acceleration. Mu cryptsetup backend is OPENSSL. After installed the module cryptodev I tested openssl

```
openssl speed  aes-256-cbc -engine cryptodev  -elapsed
   type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes   
   aes-256-cbc       8942.46k     9755.95k    10081.19k    10163.88k    10242.73k  
openssl speed -evp  aes-256-cbc -engine cryptodev  -elapsed                     
   type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes   
   aes-256-cbc        244.47k      969.43k     2942.04k     9581.57k    17539.07k
```

With and without the -evp interface. Without -evp I have no differences, with I can see a different behaviour.
After luks partition is mounted I tested writing speed with dd command, but I can't obtain any improvement by cryptodev. I think thats becasue openssl is not called by cryptsetup with the -evp option. It can be right, or have better solutions to this problem?
[edit]

```
cryptsetup benchmark -c aes-cbc  
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).  
#  Algorithm | Key |  Encryption |  Decryption  
     aes-cbc   256b    21.7 MiB/s    20.9 MiB/s
```

Comment: `cryptsetup benchmark`?

Comment: added the general benchmark, that doesn't change if cryptodev is present or not

Comment: Should it be faster? Does your CPU support hardware acceleration of AES? `grep -i flags /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`?

Comment: I'm working on embedded linux version with very low power so I think these speeds are fine. (I don't have that flag)

Comment: Then what is the actual problem?

Comment: I added the results of my two tests. As you can see with and without cryptodev (if I don't use -evp I have no improvements) results are really different (in openssl). But if I test cryptsetup have or not cryptodev is not relevant, and I can't understand why